# How do I convert an HTML string to plaintext and append it to a DIV in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Here is my issue:

I have a text variable that I get back from a jQuery post request. I parse the JSON and run a for loop. Inside the object I have some variables that look like the below.

```
post_content: "<iframe src="THEURLREMOVEDFORQUESTION" height="281" width="500" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe> Ready to plan you first visit? <a href="THEURLREMOVEDFORQUESTION">Click here</a>."
```

So when I append this to a DIV the whole iFrame appears. Does anyone know if there is a function I can use to print the characters and not render the HTML? Basically is there an easy function I can use like encode(); or something?

*Sorry if this is a duplicate. I searched for awhile and didn't find anything.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the `.text()` of the div, so it won't render the HTML, sample:

```
<div id="test"></div>

$("#test").text("<p>See this is showing the tags</p>");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w3UF4/

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV. This worked perfectly. That's why I love stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with plain JavaScript:

```
myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(post_content));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append new content to a div that may already have content use `text()` and `append()`

```
<div id="container"></div>

$("#container").append($("<div>", { text: data.post_content }).html());
```

---

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/YG48U/

Comment: You have your text and your html switched. Right now it clears out any tags. If he wants to show the tags, he should set the text of the div, then read its html.

Comment: yup, found that out creating my fiddle